# Deleting a file using a link in php

Tags: php, file, anchor, delete-file

I am making an intranet customer manager that runs on a standalone pc. The shop will add files to each of the customer records and when each record is loaded the contents of each customers folder is echo'd out on the screen inside A tags so the staff can click on it and view the documents that have been added for that customer.

I am trying to add a delete link to each of the user record pages but I'm not having much luck. I am using the following, I'm not sure if I need to get another php file to do the deleting or if I can put it into a link like this ?.

```
 echo '<a href="unlink(./customer-files/'.$customerID.'/'.$filename->getFilename().');">Delete File</a>';
```

When clicking the link all I get is >>

```
The requested URL /customermgr/unlink(./customer-files/5/customeraddnewfile.jpg); was     not found on this server.
```

EDIT >>>>

This is going on a LOCAL install, not connected to the internet, so security is not an issue here as there is ZERO chance of anyone breaking into this as its not connected to the internet. I was just looking for the quickest and simplest way of doing it without having to write too much extra code :) .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786046/delete-file-using-a-link OR http://www.tutorialarena.com/php/php-delete-file-unlink.php

Comment: This will absolutely, positively not work.  Clicking an anchor `link` will not execute arbitrary code on the server.

Answer (score 4):

You're... trying to have a link run arbitrary PHP code on the server? Do you have any idea how insecure that would be if it worked?

Instead, just have your link be:

```
echo '<a href="unlink.php?id='.$customerID.'&file='.$filename->getFilename().'">Delete</a>';
```

Then your `unlink.php` file can be something like:

```
$f = "customer-files/".$_GET['id']."/".$_GET['file'];
if( file_exists($f)) unlink($f);
```

However be aware of security implications. For example, make sure there are no instances of `../` in the filename.

Comment: Using https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php can help to make sure there are no instances of `../`.

Answer (score 1):

you can't do it like this.
You need to make the unlink call in a separated file.
In the link you give an id or other refencing the file you want to delete, then in the other file, you get this id and delete the corresponding file (after check the action is allowed).

Exemple :

in your link file :

```
<a href="unlink.php?name=customernewfile.jpg">Delete me !</a>
```

And in your "unlink.php" file :

```
...
unlink('my/path/to/files/'.$_GET['name']);
```

**It an unsercure exemple, don't use it like this.**

Answer (score 0):

You can't run a command like this through HTML as you've done. you will need to create a new PHP file and link to that:

```
<a href='delete-file.php?file=fileid'>
```

Then the php page will run the unlink command.

However be aware there are SERIOUS security issues here as people could enter any filename they choose (regardless of what you set in the HTML). Also be aware they can go up a directory by using ./ in the filepath and delete files a level higher

Comment: hi, its running on a stand alone pc so there is no way anyone can get in

Comment: In that case you should be fine, just set the delete page to `unlink ('path_to_dir/'.$_GET['fileid'])` and it should work - as long as you're happy no one will abuse it

Answer (score 0):

*If* this would have worked (it doesn't) it would mean anyone could delete basically any file by changing the href themselves.

I'm not going to slam you about how bad your idea is, but yes - you will need another php-file that grabs the query-string and then runs `unlink()` on the target.

Comment: Hi, its zero security risk as its running on a stand alone pc in a shop, not connected to the internet so its not possible for anyone to hack it. I was just trying to cut corners with it being a local install, hoping that I wouldn't have to write an extra delete script :)