# delete function in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, function

Hello am creating a CMS for website and this helps upload image into certain categories that are created by typing down the name which will be saved on the database, now I was able to also upload images into those categories and I can also delete those categories but my problem is deleting an image in a category

I created a function to do so but it does no work.

```
function deleteimagecompleted($id) {
    $id = (int) $id;
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM realest.imagecompleted WHERE mid = '$id'") or >die(mysql_error());
    header("location: editiimagecompleted.php"); 
}
```

"mid" stands for the image id in the database
"cid" is the category id in the database

Here is the code, for the image page for a category

```
<body>
<?php while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)) { ?>
<img src="<?php echo $row['path1'] ?>" /><br />
<a href=\"deleteimagecompleted.php?mid=" . $res['mid'] . "\">Delete</a>
<?php } ?>
<br />
<a href="upload.php">Add picture</a><br />
<a href="completed.php">Back</a>
</body>
```

This is the page for the deleteimagecompleted.php

```
<?php
include('editimagecompleted.php');
deleteimagecompleted($_GET['mid']);
?>
```

Please can anyone help? thanks.and if anyone need anymore info,just let me know.

Comment: You should read about [SQL INJECTION](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: Well, where to start? What does not work? What is happening? Do you receive any error messages? For the record, you are using the deprecated mysql_* library. Consider switching to mysqli_* or PDO.

Comment: Does your user has DELETE privileges for the database?

Comment: NEVER use a link to delete. If Google spiders your page, it will delete the content pointed to

Comment: @mplungjan really!damn! okay what can i do?am a noob at this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2786138/295783